# What is the cloud advert

Tags: support, bug, advertising

I keep seeing an advert which is just an image of clouds.

Clicking on it goes no where however it still has the like/dislike buttons. Is this intended or abstract subliminal advertising?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to click on it ?

Comment: +1 Saw it once. Don't know what it is... And @JonasCz , Clicking on it doesn't do anything as it isn't a link.

Comment: Uh, missed the "Clicking on it goes nowhere" bit of the question somehow.

Comment: Those are the cloud servers where the ads come from. This seems perfectly ordinary and reasonable to me.

Comment: Actually, having these as an "ad" is kinda nice.. Especially if they are done only with CSS, avoiding an image download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To date, I've experienced two use-cases that cause the cloud image to serve.

1. A creative tag set up incorrectly on our side. This is easy to fix, as PEBKAC issues can be.
2. The creative is serving outside it's intended geo. Basically: an advertiser generated a creative tag intended to target *only* the UK, but it is being served outside of the UK.

I've checked all likely culprits (I know which advertiser provides tags that do this), and looked at campaigns targeting the UK, and can't seem to reproduce the error. Please reply here to let me know if you see this problem again. I'm not marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) just yet, I'll give it a few days.

Comment: Curous: How come you are a moderator, but not seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)?

Comment: @CoolGuy I'm a Stack Exchange employee. I work on the Ad Operations team-- which explains my ability to answer the question. :-)

Comment: @CoolGuy - do you see me there? Or any of the other devs?

Comment: @Oded , Nope...

Comment: @stevvve still being served up, makes a nice change an ad that sparks curiosity.

Comment: @Skuld I'm 90% certain this is a client-facing issue. Reaching out to fix this, though I think you all may like it more if they don't-- those cloud placeholders seem to be a favorite around here! :-)

Comment: Seen again today on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object (for UK computer) I have a screen shot aswell though not sure that helps.

Comment: @stevvve I rather like the clouds so won't complain if it keeps happening :)

Comment: I still see the clouds on a daily basis.

Comment: @John Yep, you're going to continue to see it until the current creative expires today. I let the client know a while ago, but they don't seem very motivated to fix the issue. :-)

Comment: Ok, not to worry just though you may want to know