# Ad is just clouds

Tags: bug, advertising

I just got an ad that was just clouds:

[image: clouds]

Judging by the [previous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292332/why-an-image-of-clouds-made-of-dots-as-an-ad) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296351/what-is-the-cloud-advert) something like this came up, there's probably a configuration error somewhere. This ad actually went somewhere, though. [Here's the link it went to](https://www.ibm.com/thought-leadership/behindthecode/), minus the doubleclick redirect and the query string, because I have no idea what might be encoded there.

Comment: It's not an ad, it's decoration!

Comment: It's not an ad, it's a link to Meta SkyOverflow.

Comment: If we can't make developers go Outside, we'll bring the Outside to the developers. Whatever it takes.

Comment: If you think about it, you clicked it, because you didn't know where it lead. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Congratulations, you found the missing Winter Bash hat!

Comment: You might think those are clouds, but they're just other peoples' computers

Comment: After clicking this, I'm glad the title was succinctly summed up by the first sentence.

Comment: Maybe that's the new ad concept to get your attention, let's put something simple and unclear, the mystery, the curiosity, it will make them click. Mouhahahahaha

Comment: Between the add itself, and the link in this post, I would guess this is one of the most clicked ads on Stackoverflow!

Comment: It [happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349673/1364007) in 2017 too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! We have identified which advertiser this ad relates to and have notified them of the issue. The most common reason the cloud ad is served is that an ad tag is being implemented improperly. We are working to correct this, so you should not be seeing any clouds in the future (unless of course it's a cloudy day).